# NUXT JS SassError: Undefined variable "$black"

Tags: sass, global-variables, nuxt.js

I declare an SCSS variable `$black` in my file `general.scss` and in `default.vue` I want to use it but I have this error `SassError: Undefined variable "$black"`.

I'm using Nuxt.js!

[screenshot variable declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4S4zv.png)

[screenshot variable utilisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lez7p.png)

[screenshot organisation folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFG0P.png)

If you have any response or help for me, thank you and sorry for my bad english :) !

[EDIT]

I don't know why but my account is blocked, so the solution of my problemes is in this [tutorial](https://dev.to/ceppeu/using-sass-global-variables-in-nuxt-js-j0k)

Thanks all for your times (love)

Answer (score 4):

Try importing your file without using `url()`. Like this:

```
@import '@/assets/style/general.scss';
```

I hope that solves your issue, it worked for me.

---

Also, if you use those variables in a lot of different components you could consider using the [@nuxtjs/style-resources](https://github.com/nuxt-community/style-resources-module) module to automatically import it everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I used the Sass `@use` rule, because support for the `@import` rule will be dropped according to this [timeline](https://github.com/sass/sass/blob/main/accepted/module-system.md#timeline).

Example:

```html
<style lang="scss">
    @use '@/assets/style/general.scss';
    
    h2 {
        color: general.$black;
    }
</style>
```

By default, the namespace is just the last component of the module’s URL.